# How do I make Quick Access in Windows 10 update to the Folder Redirections path?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a Domain Network configured with Group Policy to enable folder redirection on all client machines for Desktop, Documents etc.

This group policy is applied and works perfectly, however, the Quick Access shortcuts in Windows 10 File Explorer all update to {servername}\Folder Redirection{username} except for the Desktop - This stays pointing at C:\Users{username}\Desktop as opposed to the server redirection location.

The only way I've managed to make this work is manually unpinning the Desktop Shortcut then re-adding it. This isn't convenient as all these machines get used by multiple users so if they swap machine, even if briefly, these shortcuts don't work unless they call me in or use another direction through explorer.

Has anyone come across this or have any suggestions?